# How to append an array inside another array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of `selectedWeekdays` and I want to append the `shifts` array in the `Weekday` object.

For instance, I want to append the array of shifts for every instance in `selectedWeekdays` where `name` is equal to `Monday`

```
struct Weekday: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var index: Int
    var shifts: [Shift]
}

struct Shift: Identifiable, Encodable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date
}

@Published var selectedWeekdays: [Weekday] = []
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
self.selectedWeekdays.contains(where: {$0.name == weekday}).shifts.append({Shift(startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)})
```

It shows the following error:
`Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'shifts'`

Comment: `contains(where:)` returns a`Bool` you can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/contains(where:)) Do you perhaps mean to use `filter` or even `forEach`?

Comment: @Andrew I tried using `filter` as well but with little success. I'm not sure about `ForEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use to get the certain item, but it might require you to unwrap the optional first.

```
if var item = selectedWeekdays.first(where: {$0.name == weekday}) {
    item.shifts.append(your new element)
}
```

Edited:

Code above only works if you define your Weekday as a class. If you want to stick with structs, it's not that pretty but works,

```
struct Weekday {
 
    // Properties
    // ..

    mutating func updateShifts(for weekdays: String, with newShift: Shift) {
        if self.name == weekdays {
            self.shifts.append(newShift)
        }
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
for i in 0..<selectedWeekdays.count {
    selectedWeekdays[i].updateShifts(for: "Monday", with: newShift)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this throws the error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'item' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: updated the answer, you can use if var item = ... @devOP1

Comment: This is the closest answer so far. The only problem is that it uses a different instance of `selectedWeekdays`. It essentially makes a copy of the array

Comment: @devOP1 yeah I noticed that, trying to figure it out, easiest solution to prevent that is to convert struct type to class type for Weekday.

Comment: edited my solution, not sure if you want to do it like this way tho. @devOP1

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` returns `boolean` and you are trying to use as the array of the Weekday itself.

To filter the array and return the same structure, you must use the `filter` function and iterate with them using `compactMap` (which iterates to every not null elemen, transform the object and returns the modified object).

But like @Andrew remembered every item is immutable, this happens because we are using a `Sequence`'s method. So to modify the object we need to new and mutable object of the same Class and then insert it into our new array.

Finally, use the result of `compactMap`to get the array with the inserted element.

```swift
    let modifiedSelectedWeekdays = selectedWeekdays
        .filter { $0.name == weekday }
        .compactMap { item -> Weekday in
            var mutable = item
            
            mutable.shifts.append(
                Shift(startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
            )

            return mutable
        }
```

Comment: Won't you get a mutating member error as $0 is immutable?

Comment: I would like to append the `shifts` array on a particular weekday using the `name` property of `Weekday`. If you could please include that in the answer

Comment: @devOP1 so using a filter would help you. I changed my answer to meet your expectations

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work as @Andrew mentioned, it throws an error

Comment: @devOP1 I edited again. I hope this solution works